# Negotiate authentication and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, integration-testing

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) recommends to use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing) for integration tests and it seems to be a great choice, but it seems that they missed to add the ability to test with [NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).

Adding to Startup.cs/ConfigureServices

```
 services.AddAuthentication (NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate ();
```

causes the tests to fail with

> Message: 
>       System.NotSupportedException : Negotiate authentication requires a server that supports IConnectionItemsFeature like Kestrel.

Does anybode know how to use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing) with endpoints that use NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme? Is it just not supported, like the exception claims?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That is not supported by design](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19933#issuecomment-615890398)

> WebApplicationFactory doesn't use kestrel, it uses the in-memory TestServer and in-memory HttpClient. Neither of those support the features needed for Negotiate auth.

I dropped  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing and used a custom NUnit base class instead:

```
public class AspNetCoreIntegrationTestBase
{
  public CancellationTokenSource? CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

  public Task? TestWebserver { get; set; }

  [OneTimeSetUp]
  public void Setup()
  {
    CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    TestWebserver = Program.CreateHostBuilder(Array.Empty<string>()).Build().StartAsync(CancellationTokenSource.Token);
  }

  [OneTimeTearDown]
  public void CleanUp()
  {
    CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    TestWebserver?.Dispose();
  }
}
```

The httpclient to use needs to be initialized with

```
UseDefaultCredentials = true
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a much better way to do this my dudes :) and its supported way. check this out, we can implement `IServerIntegratedAuth`

```
public class TestServerIntegratedAuth : IServerIntegratedAuth
{
    public bool IsEnabled => true;

    public string AuthenticationScheme => "TestScheme";
}
```

this will instruct `NegotiateHandles` to forward authentication to `TestScheme`, then in tests you can add this `IServerIntegratedAuth` implementation to a container and register `TestScheme` if you want to perform authentication

```
var client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(b =>
    {
        b.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IServerIntegratedAuth, TestServerIntegratedAuth>();

            services
                .AddAuthentication()
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>("TestScheme", options => { });
        });

    }).CreateDefaultClient();
```

this `TestAuthHandler` is from [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#mock-authentication)

```
public class TestAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public TestAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test user") };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "TestScheme");

        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

and that's it. Works like a charm.

The same thing `IIS` integration implements in order to perform negotiation natively.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution per se, but if you don't want to change your entire testing framework from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` to something else, the following temporary workaround may suffice you. Simply turn off security as follows and run your test.

In `Program.cs`, comment these lines out:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Also turn off authorization in the controller you are testing, as by commenting out the `Authorize` attribute:

```
//[Authorize]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can run your tests. Just don't forget to reverse the changes when you're done.